# PostgreSQL - return months even where there are no records within that month

Tags: sql, postgresql

first of all thank you for helping me, this is my first JR job and I don't want to screw this up.

I need to return all the records (grouped by price and money_balance) of a Debts history by month, of Property for a specific year.

What I've been trying to do is

```
SELECT properties.name as property
    , EXTRACT(month from priority_date) as month
    , SUM(debts.money_balance) as money_balance
    , SUM(debts.price) as price
FROM properties
JOIN debts on properties.id = debts.property_id
WHERE properties.community_id = 15 
AND properties.active = TRUE 
AND EXTRACT(year from priority_date) = 2021
GROUP BY month, properties.name
```

This is going to give me something like

| id | property | month | money_balance | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 1 | 1111 | 3131 |
| 2 | A1 | 7 | 0 | 1111 |
| 3 | A2 | 7 | 0 | 1111 |

But I need to have even months where there are no records, and to have the money_balance and price at 0 or null, if this achievable with SQL?

Thank you so much.

Edit:

```
Desired output: 
|id|property | month|money_balance| price|
|--| ---     | ---- |--           | ---- |
|1 | A1      |1     |1111         | 3131 |
|2 |A1       |2     | 0           |0     |
|3 |A1       |3     | 0           |0     |
```

Till month 12, it ca be 0 or null in the months were the are no records

Comment: show us your desired output as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_series()` to generate all the months, and then bring the data in:

```
SELECT p.name as property, mon,
       SUM(d.money_balance) as money_balance,
       SUM(d.price) as price
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 12, 1) gs(mon) JOIN
     (properties p JOIN
      debts d
      ON p.id = d.property_id AND
         p.community_id = 15 AND
         p.properties.active = TRUE AND
         EXTRACT(year from priority_date) = 2021
     )
     ON EXTRACT(month from priority_date) = gs.mon
GROUP BY gs.mon, p.name
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I was trying to run it but it is giving me "Missing FROM-clause entry for table "properties" ", I'm trying to modify it

Comment: @tryingtobeabetterdev . . . I thought I had removed the `WHERE` clause.